# Speed up a pip install process that contains a build step

Tags: python, pypi

```
# setup.py
from setuptools import setup
from setuptools.command.install import install
from subprocess import check_call

class CustomInstall(install):
    def run(self):
        check_call("./build.sh")
        install.run(self)

setup(
    name='customlib',
    packages=['customlib'],
    version='0.0.1',
    ...
    cmdclass={'install': CustomInstall}
)
```

`build.sh` contains a `make & make install` step which takes **more than 10 minutes** to finish.

Is there a PyPi way to "package" the output of `build.sh` to speed up the `pip install` process?

Answer (score 1):

Use [wheel](http://pythonwheels.com/). A wheel is a great standard format for passing around Python packages, and it can contain C code compiled for various architectures. PyPI supports uploading wheels for your project, and pip will download them when available.

Very useful docs can be found here: https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/distributing-packages/#packaging-your-project